# Estimating Flash project hours

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to estimate the hours required to build a group of 5 simple children's games in Flash. They will include such things as having kids drag and drop healthy food items into a basket; choosing the healthy and unhealthy food items by marking them in some way; etc.

I have no experience building games in Flash, but I have programmed in Flex and Actionscript. How many hours do you estimate for this project?

Comment: You may want to break it down feature by feature and ask the developers to give an estimate, as they know best what their skills are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your ActionScript background will help, I find Flash to be a VERY different experience from Flex and that proficiency in one environment does not translate well.

Is there a compelling reason not to use Flex?  I think you would likely be much more efficient.

That aside, the mechanics of a simple drag and drop game could be put together fairly quickly. There are some good examples of basic drag and drop around.  It can be a little tricky to get the mouse coordinates right if it is your first time.

That aside, there are other hidden costs you need to remember.  Connecting infrastructure for example.  Are the games connected in some way?  Is there a running score or persistence that might imply authentication? Is there a story?

Also, If your forte is programming, don't underestimate that challenges of obtaining or creating art and sound assets.

Comment: +1 For assets making. Especially when it comes to vector art, artists are rare and doing it yourself might not get you to the quality you intended.

Comment: @didibus: as a graphic designer I'd disagree that artists are rare. There are loads of talented artists with nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can estimate the time you'll need to break down what the games do.  In other words, you'll need to write up very clear and definite requirements.  You may even need to write up specifications.  Once you've analyzed what the software should do, the estimate will also take a while - one part for example is figuring out whether there's already software that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Liz. The only issue is we're hiring an instructional designer to write up the games' requirements/specs. We're right now writing the grant proposal for this and don't have the details.

Comment: Then an estimate from your designer would be helpful, but if not, you may have to write the proposal making it clear you're only offering an estimate on the resources you'll require.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way you can possibly estimate a programming project, especially one in a technology you don't understand, would be to apply the Use Case Points methodology.  Basically you break the project up into use-cases (what the users are trying to do) and actors (the user types and the system itself) and then list a few team and environment factors (how big an issue is code re-use, how familiar are you with the lanaguage, etc.)  Studies have shown that it's more accurate for inexperienced developers than estimating based on features alone.

A google search for "use case points estimate" reveals many useful links.  [This explanation of the methodology](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=25) seems to do a good job explaining how it works, though I've not read the entire thing.  [This worksheet](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/2785418/Use-Case-Point-Estimation-Worksheet) will help when you're ready to start listing points.